# Allegation concept clarity regarding total mixture?

Tags: ratio

"In a jar there is mixture of milk and water in the ratio of 7:5. 9 liters of mixture was taken out and replaced by same quantity of water and after that the ratio becomes 7:9 in the jar. find out original quantity of mixture or find out quantity of milk in jar?"

After solving this by allegation i got ratio of mixture and water 3:1. if 1 is equal to 9 then 3 must be equal to 27 and 3 was total mixture so total mixture was 27 liters according to me. but the answer is total mixture was 36(27+9).

I can't understand why?

Please clear

Comment: Can you explain your procedure of solving by allegation?

Comment: i will upload image of my method

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be the total mixture volume in litres. Assume that the mixture is well-mixed, so that the $9$ litre sample also has a milk-water ratio of $7:5$. Let's focus on the milk.

Originally, we start with $\frac{7}{12}x$ litres of milk. We remove $\frac{7}{12}(9)$ litres of milk from this mixture and replace it with $\frac{7}{12}(9)$ litres of water. Finally, we should end up with $\frac{7}{16}x$ of milk. Thus, we have:
\begin{align*}
\frac{7}{12}(x - 9) &= \frac{7}{16}x \\
16(x - 9) &= 12x \\
4(x - 9) &= 3x \\
4x - 36 &= 3x \\
x &= 36
\end{align*}

Comment: thanks@adriano but i know this method. i am confused about allegation method